# Cannot invoke “pageObject.loginPage.enter_username(String)” because “this.LoginPage” is null

Tags: automated-testing

I'm automating a simple login test project with cucumber + maven + testng. I can't write username and password in login page I can't login https://www.lambdatest.com/automation-demos/ website. Where is my mistake? What am I doing wrong.

```
   public class loginPage extends TestBase {
    
    public loginPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using ="//input[@id='username']")
    WebElement uss;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using ="//input[@id='password']")
    WebElement pss;

    @FindBy(how = How.CSS, using=".applynow")
    WebElement buttonLogin;
    
    public void enter_username(String user) {
        uss.sendKeys(user); 
    }

    public void enter_password(String pass) {
        pss.sendKeys(pass);
    }
    public void enter_buttonLogin() {
        buttonLogin.click();
    }   
    
}

public class loginPageSteps extends TestBase{
    
    loginPage LoginPage;
    
    @Given("I open the login page")
    public void i_open_the_login_page() throws InterruptedException {
        TestBase.initialization();
    }

    @When("^I fill username \"([^\"]*)\" and password \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_fill_username_and_password(String username, String password) {
        
        LoginPage.enter_username(username);
        LoginPage.enter_password(password);
        LoginPage.enter_buttonLogin();
    }
    
    @Then("I should see the success login message \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"")
    public void i_should_see_the_success_login_message(String string) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
    }

}
```

My TestBase Code:

```
public class TestBase {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static WebDriverWait wait;
public static Properties properties;
public static String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");

public TestBase() {

    properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(currentDirectory + "//src//test//resources//config.properties"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void initialization() {
    String browserName = properties.getProperty("browser");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
        // driver = new ChromeDriver();
        ChromeOptions optns = new ChromeOptions();
        optns.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(optns);
        System.out.println("Browser is set to Chrome");
    } else if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("Browser is set to Firefox");
    } else {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        System.out.println("Browser is set to IE");
    }
    // driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get(properties.getProperty("url"));
}

public static void closeBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define an instance of login page first. In `loginPageSteps` class and in `i_fill_username_and_password` method, first add this line:

```
LoginPage = new loginPage();
```

then call `enter_username` and all other methods you write.

Note: Actually you should read more about Naming convention in java in order to help you make your application more understandable.
You should name a class with capital letter and the instance of the class with lower letter. In your case it would be better to define `LoginPage` as the class name and `loginPage` as the instance of that class.
Although it's not mandatory but makes your application easy to read.